# Which is correct: "read a Bible" or "read the Bible"?

Tags: word-choice, articles, indefinite-article

‘The’ is used when you’re talking about something/someone specific and ‘a’ is used when you are not and there are many of the thing you are talking about. 
I don’t think these examples fit the above. Can you explain how it does?

> 1. He used to read **the** Bible but he doesn’t anymore.
> 2. Christians read **the** Bible.

There are many Bibles so shouldn’t these sentences be:

> 1. He used to read **a** Bible but he doesn’t anymore.
> 2. Christians read **a** Bible.

But this sounds very wrong. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, you *can* say "a bible" if you're referring to one of many physical,  printed versions of the book.

> I have two bibles in my house, a bible from my grandmother's family, and a bible from my grandfather's.
>
> [Why is there a Bible in every hotel room?](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1477/why-is-there-a-bible-in-every-hotel-room)

When you say "the Bible," however, you're referring to the literary work itself, rather than a specific *instance* or *printed version* of the work.  I think we simply think of it as a proper noun, as though "the" is *part of the title*.

Looking into this I did find [this discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217306/why-are-religious-texts-the-bible-the-torah-the-quran-preceded-by-th), which may be of interest.  It didn't seem to come to a consensus as to why this is grammatically, but some users mentioned the etymology of the word as likely contributing to this usage.  "Bible" comes Latin *biblia* meaning simply "book."  Essentially, people used to simply refer to it as "the book," and I suppose the definite article just stuck around while "Bible" evolved into a word of its own.

Worth noting is that there are a lot of historical literary works whose names use *the*, including religious texts (*The Torah*, *The Qur'an*) and epic poems (*The Iliad*, *The Aeneid*).

Comment: Link was helpful too!